# Updating or uploading CSS format style to GeoServer through REST API

Tags: style, geoserver-rest-api

I have tried that:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/css" -d @data_clone.css http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sde/styles/style_clone.css
```

It does not change anything.
The way is working well for SLD type-styles. But I can not find any tutorial for CSS type styles to upload or update syle.

There is no error. It responses nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content type should be `application/vnd.geoserver.geocss+css`.

Also, check the result status and headers, they probably contain some useful information, by adding either "-v" or "-D" to the curl command lines.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.

Comment: Now I can update existed style. When I am creating style it says default style. How can I specify, style name, file name, the format in this content type?